# Dirac delta function in spherical cordinates

Tags: functions, dirac-delta, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I am studying Dirac Delta Function in Spherical Polar Cordinates. I found this expression

$$\delta\ ^3 (\vec r -\vec r_{o}) = \frac{ \delta\ (r -r_{o})\delta\  (θ -θ_{o})\delta\ (φ -φ_{o}  )}{r^2 \sin θ }$$

And then they have reduced it to

$$\delta\ ^3 (\vec r -\vec r_{o}) = \frac{ \delta\ (r -r_{o})\delta\  (θ -θ_{o}) }{2πr^2 \sin θ }$$

How do we get this reduced expression from the above expression? Please explain.

Comment: Compute $\int\limits_{r=0}^\infty \int\limits_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} \delta(r-r_0) \delta(\theta - \theta_0) r\ dr\ d\theta$ and you'll get non-unity value.  Given you demand the integral = 1.0, these give you the scaling constants.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that two expressions are equal. Note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}f(r,\theta,\phi)\delta(\phi-\phi_0)\,d\phi&=f(r,\theta,\phi_0)\\\\
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{2\pi}f(r,\theta,\phi)\,d\phi&\ne f(r,\theta,\phi_0)
\end{align}$$

unless $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ is independent of $\phi$.

Comment: @dineshkatoch Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.